# VBA - Pasting/Inserting a range without formatting shifted down

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably pretty simple but as a beginner I am not sure how to combine these two codes into one.

Right now I use this code to copy and paste a table into specific range.
`Sheet3.Range("MyTable").Copy
Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12:D12").Insert Shift:=xlDown`

Now I want to paste it without formatting and this code should do the work:

```
Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12:D12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

All I need to do is add the `Shift:=xlDown` to the second code somehow... Is it possible to do it all in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this solution where 1st- we copy + insert as previously, 2nd- we copy to paste with values to overwrite what was inserted:

```
Sheet3.Range("MyTable").Copy
Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12:D12").Insert Shift:=xlDown

With Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12").Resize(Sheet3.Range("MyTable").Rows.Count, Sheet3.Range("MyTable").Columns.Count)

    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in two lines but you have to keep the right order of all instructions:

```
Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12:D12").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Sheet3.Range("MyTable").Copy
Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

It could be also required the following line before `.insert`:

```
application.CutCopyMode = false
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me unfortunately. If I do it in two lines I need the first line to insert blank rows only... Is there really no way to have two "arguments" in one line?

Comment: I did some test and it didn't work for me, so it is rather not possible. You could try to **copy > paste** as you did and next try to **copy > pastespecial** only for what was inserted, in `MyWorksheet sheet`. I will delete this answer later.

Comment: That makes sense to me but how do I do that? You have already helped a lot with that comment so thank you even if you don't have the time to write the code...